# Copying files from one model to another

Tags: django

I have two models like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    attachment = FileField(upload_to='a')

class B(models.Model):
    attachment = FileField(upload_to='b')
```

I have instance of **A** model:

```
a = A.objects.get(pk=1)
```

I need to create instance of **B** model, with file copied from **a** instance.

How can I do that?

I was trying something like this, but it is not working:

```
from django.core.files import File
B.objects.create(attachment=File(open(a.attachment.path, 'rb')))
```

Comment: Any error trace ?
Or it's just not working as you want ?
I tried your code in a new project and it's working, but you should write B.objects.create(attachment=a.attachment).

Comment: Did you try `a.attachment = b.attachment`?

Comment: It says something about row 1 data truncated. If use b.attachment = a.attachment it will be the same file located in folder for model A. I need copy of this file in directory for model B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It strange thing. Now the way I tryed before works perfectly, without any errors.
Maybe I missed something at the first time. So it works:

```
from django.core.files import File
B.objects.create(attachment=File(open(a.attachment.path, 'rb')))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it like this, hope it helps anybody:

```
# models.py

class A(models.Model):
    # other fields...
    attachment = FileField(upload_to='a')

class B(models.Model):
    # other fields...
    attachment = FileField(upload_to='b')

# views.py or any file you need the code in

try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from main.models import A, B

obj1 = A.objects.get(pk=1)

# You and either copy the file to an existent object
obj2 = B.objects.get(pk=2)

# or create a new instance
obj2 = B(**some_params)

tmp_file = StringIO(obj1.attachment.read())
tmp_file = ContentFile(tmp_file.getvalue())
url = obj1.attachment.url.split('.')
ext = url.pop(-1)
name = url.pop(-1).split('/')[-1]  # I have my files in a remote Storage, you can omit the split if it doesn't help you
tmp_file.name = '.'.join([name, ext])
obj2.attachment = tmp_file

# Remember to save you instance
obj2.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, but doesn't create a new file.

For creating a new file, you should consider shutil.copy() : http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html

Moreover, if you copy a file, its name has to be different from the previous one, or you can keep the same name if you create the file in another **directory**. It Depends what you want...

So your code becomes :

```
from shutil import copy
B.objects.create(attachment=copy(a.attachment.path, 'my_new_path_or_my_new_filename'))
```

Also don't forget to `.save()` your new object.

Comment: This way is a bit complicated. I need to check if file exists, generate filename, get upload_to attribute from model field, etc. I am sure here is an easier way.

Comment: You can do all these verifications before...
Using 'try: except:' for your validations etc...
I don't see an easier way to do it (currently one line).

Comment: @GuillaumeCisco I have a similar problem with the copying of a file. Would you please loot at my question and answer if possible.